# Unable to access global variable in main function | python

Tags: python, program-entry-point

I wanted to understand, how global scope works in `if __name__ == '__main__'`: Block 
E.g:

```
x = 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global x
    x = 10
    print(x)
```

The above will throw an exception:

```
global x
    ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: name 'x' is assigned to before global declaration
```

But, when I'm creating an new function and calling global in it then its working fine.

```
x=10
def test():
    global x
    x=2
    print(x)
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
    print(x)
```

It's working fine without any error. I'm just trying to understand what's happening here.
When python file is called, it will invoke if **name** == '**main**': and then access the global variable

Comment: Your second code fragment prints **10**. Is that what you expected?

Comment: You cant use global in the same scope as the variable already defined

Comment: @DarkKnight I'm just trying to understand the variable scope. How global scope work in __name__== '__main__' block

Answer (score 2):

When a python file is executed, it is executed line-by-line from the top down.
So in your first example, x is set to 2 first, `if __name__ == '__main__':` turns out to be True so then `global x` is called. Since x already exists on a global scale, this throws a `SyntaxError`.

In your second example, the function `min` is never called, since you did not put `()` after the functon. The line `min` actually **returns** the method, but **does not call** it. So the `SyntaxError` never arises, but the value of x is also not changed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I fixed my code snippet.
I just wanted to understand, how if __name__ == '__main__': global scope work under this block

Answer (score -1):

Well I think it's a problem with the installation of python;
I tried it on my system and it runs, consider reinstalling python and its libraries.
Alternatively run the file manually like

'''
python {filename}.py
'''

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question

Comment: What is this answering (if anything)?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).